# is there any performance impacts of using whole methods as public in java?

Tags: java, performance

Are there any performance impacts of using method as a public even there is no need to access that method outside the class?

Comment: I doubt it. Though it might be a security risk or make harder what is your intended interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There is no performance impact to making your methods more visible. But, it is not considered a best practice to expose more methods then necessary for the function of your code.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tiny performance impact but it is related to whether the method is override-able and not to whether the method is public. Roughly speaking a method which meets all of the following:

- non `private`
- non `static`
- non `final`

Is considered overridable (that is: can be overridden by a method in a subclass) and thus the compiler cannot determine (at compilation time) the exact implementation that is to be invoked at a given call site. Thus, there is a runtime machinery to carry out this resolution when the call is actually made (a.k.a *dynamic binding*). This runtime resolution is realized by a very efficient implementation, and is typically heavily optimized by the JVM based on the program's behavior, so the overall penalty is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Using public methods when there is no need to invoke them outside the class scope raise security issues and not performance issues.

Comment: Design issues, maintainability issues, backward compatibility issues, yes. But why would it raise security issues? Access modifiers are not security tools. Anyone can access private state with reflection. Access modifiers are design tools

Comment: @JBNizet Anyone with the security permission to do so, given an installed security manager :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Anyone able to load that class; the creator of the VM instance is the ony who controls what SecurityManager any class *may* install ;)

Comment: @Durandal No attack will happen when a hacker runs the class's code on his own laptop, so that's hardly a security concern.